# Can't remove code analysis warning C26462

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, code-analysis, visual-studio-2022

Sample code:

```
void COptionsDlg::OnBnClickedButtonMoreSettings()
{
    CString strCaption = _T("");
    const auto pMoreSettingsButton = GetDlgItem(IDC_BUTTON_MORE_SETTINGS);

    if (pMoreSettingsButton == nullptr)
        return;

    pMoreSettingsButton->GetWindowText(strCaption);

    __pragma(warning(suppress:26414))
        auto pDlgOther = std::make_unique<COtherSettingsSheet>(strCaption);
    if (pDlgOther != nullptr)
    {
        pDlgOther->DoModal();
    }
}
```

Why does the compiler still complain about this line:

[image]

It still says:

> [C26462](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26462?view=msvc-160): The value pointed to by `pMoreSettingsButton` is assigned only once, mark it as a pointer to `const` (con.4).

I am using Visual Studio 2022 Preview 6 and I have noticed this with other class files. Is it something I am doing wrong or a bug I should address to Microsoft?

Comment: I think it wants you to do `const CWnd* pMoreSettingsButton = ...;` Whereas `const auto` makes it `CWnd* const` - the pointer itself is const, not the pointee. The value of this advice is questionable, in my humble opinion.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You are right - changing it like that stops it from displaying.

Comment: Unrelated, but the `unique_ptr` further down isn't really necessary. You can just make the dialog a local variable, i.e. `COtherSettingsSheet dlg(strCaption); dlg.DoModal();`, and everything gets cleaned up on function exit.

Comment: @IInspectable The reason I do that sometimes is when the code analysis says the functions stack size is too big or something (can't quite remember). But making changing like this those warnings go away.

Comment: That makes sense. Stack size is pretty limited (1MB by default), so placing large objects on the stack can quickly deplete that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following program captures the gist of the issue, without loss of generality:

```cpp
int* foo() { return nullptr; }

int main() {
    const auto p = foo();  // C26462
}
```

It produces a [C26462](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26462) diagnostic, and goes on to provide a solution:

> mark it as a pointer to `const`

You might think that `const auto` does exactly that, but it doesn't.

The compiler needs to infer what to substitute `auto` for. It looks at the function declaration for `foo()` and unambiguously concludes, that `auto` should get substituted for `int*`. That part isn't very interesting. The only surprise here may be, that C++ is following the route of least surprises.

So, then, if `auto` gets replaced with `int*`, it would appear obvious that `const auto` should turn into `const int*`, i.e. a pointer to `const`, just as the diagnostic message suggested. Why is the code analyzer still complaining then?

Well, taking the route of least surprises isn't the *only* option you have when designing a programming language, and C++ isn't shy to aggressively explore *that* design space, too! Placement of the `const` keyword certainly falls into that category:

Broadly speaking, `const` applies to whatever is immediately to the left of it. That's simple, deceptively so, very unlike C++. And sure, there's also a special rule that's seeing such frequent application that we almost entirely forgot that it's special: If there isn't anything to the left of `const` then it gets applied to whatever is immediately to the right of it. For values, this doesn't matter much: `const int` and `int const` mean the same thing. When pointers are involved, though, things get more interesting. `const int*` and `int* const` mean something completely different. The former designates a *"pointer to `const`"* whereas the latter is a *"`const` pointer"*.

Going back to the immediate issue here, `const auto` gets translated to `auto const` (by way of the special `const` rule), and finally `auto` is substituted, producing `int* const` (or `CWnd* const` as in the initial problem statement). This is **not** a *"pointer to `const`"*. To solve the issue, you have two options:

- Name the concrete type, i.e. `CWnd const*`, or
- have `auto` resolve to something else, e.g. `auto const*` (note the trailing `*` that causes the compiler to infer the type `CWnd`, and allows you to cv-qualify the pointee)

Either way, you should consider using [*"consistent `const`"*, also referred to as *"east `const`"*](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-ref-alt), and forget that there even is a special rule for `const`.

Comment: I also had a reply here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/c26462-and-datetimechange/1574439#T-N1575286. In short `const auto* pMoreSettingsButton = GetDlgItem(IDC_BUTTON_MORE_SETTINGS);` is sufficient.